# Converting Ethernet to a WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a outside building that is too far away from to house to detect any signal from our house's WiFi network.
If I run an Ethernet cable to it, could i convert that Ethernet into a WiFi signal, and if so which device do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can achieve what you want. Hook up the House end of the Ethernet to a LAN port on your house network.

Now get a decent wireless router for the outside building. Hook it up as follows to have everything on the same network:

LAN port on the wireless router for the Ethernet Cable (which is LAN port on the other (House)end.

Give the wireless router a static IP on the main network.

On the wireless router, in the LAN section, turn DHCP OFF.

This works well in all my installs of this sort.

I do assume the Outside building is within 100 Meters (300 Feet) of the house.

Answer (score 1):

An access point is the device you are looking for. You can think of it like a switch that includes wifi hosts.
I also think that running an ethernet cable to that building is the ideal way to do this, compared to devices like wifi repeaters. A very nice addition is also the injection of PoE through the ethernet cable resulting in ethernet + power to drive that access point at the end of that cable.

Edit: Johns comment below is basically how to turn an existing router into an AP. Sometimes you dont even have to do all this manually if it has a "AP mode". His reply is a very nice approach if you have a router laying around, if not my suggestion is to buy an AP.